# How to remove everything from URL except domain with sed?

Tags: linux, sed

I need to remove everything from a URL and keep only domain.

Before sed examples:

https://www.something.com/something/something 
https://www.something.com:8080/something/something

After sed:

something.com

Comment: 1st hit on Google https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497215/how-to-extract-domain-name-from-url

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
$ url1='https://www.something.com:8080/something/something'
$ url2='http://www.someting.com/something/something'
$ printf "%s\n%s\n" "$url1" "$url2" | \
>   sed -e 's|^.*://||' \
>       -e 's|/.*$||' \
>       -e 's|:.*$||' \
>       -e 's|^.*@||' \
www.something.com
www.someting.com
```

This chains four `sed` expressions together:

- `s|^.*://||`: Delete everything from the start up-to and including `://`
- `s|/.*$||`: Delete everything remaining from the first slash to the end
- `s|:.*$||`: Delete everything remaining from the first colon to the end
- `s|^.*@||`: deletes everything up-to and including `@` ex: `ftp://user:pass@site.com`

You are left with `www.something.com`.  `www` is actually part of the domain.  (`unix.stackexchange.com` has a different IP than `math.stackexchange.com`)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `URI` module of Perl to pull out the hostname from the URL, and then a substitution to delete `www.` from the start from that hostname:

```bash
perl -MURI -ple '$_ = URI->new($_)->host(); s/^www\.//'
```

Testing:

```bash
$ cat file
https://www.something.com/something/something
https://www.something.com:8080/something/something
https://something.com:999/something/something
```

```bash
$ perl -MURI -ple '$_ = URI->new($_)->host(); s/^www\.//' <file
something.com
something.com
something.com
```

Answer (score 0):

With `grep` implementations that support `perl`-like regular expressions with `-P` and a `-o` option such as GNU `grep`:

```
grep -iPo '://([^/@]*@)?(www\.)?\K(\[.*?\]|[^:/]+)'
```

`([^/@]*@)?` in an attempt to skip the `user:pass@` part if any, `\[.*?\]` to take care of `https://[abcd::cdef]/ipv6` URLs.

Best would be to use a proper URI parser like with [@Kusalananda's approach](/a/708982) though.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/[^.]*\.([[:alpha:].]+).*/\1/' input_file
something.com
something.com
```